# How can I setup the database for Widgetkit plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

We have a Wordpress 4.0 installation in our dev server. We installed [Widgetkit](https://yootheme.com/widgetkit/downloads) (paid version) and althought the wordpress database is configured (this means: the WP installation could be done with no issues, and we can access the administration backend and successfully login).

However, when trying to create a slideshow (or a gallery), it doesn't work (it doesn't store in database). After reading the logs (apache error log), I see this error:

> PHP Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'myserverstartuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /path/to/server/www/wp-content-plugins/widgetkit/helpers/widget.php on line 90, referer: http://my.server.dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=widgetkit&task=save_slideshow

(`myserverstartuser` stands for the linux user used to start the server; by default is `www-data`).

I went to such line in the plugin and saw:

```
'post_content' => mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($data)),
```

It is not a complete line, but part of a statement. However the issue is clear:

- No link is passed for the `mysql_real_escape_string` function, and so a new link is tried to be established and used. Additionaly, no previous link is open.
- To establish a link, `mysql_connect` is called with no arguments.
- Such call needs the right arguments (the same arguments as in WP installation), and since the call has no arguments, each parameter is populated with the default values (values obtained from `ini_get`).
- [After searching in the whole plugin folder i noticed] the plugin itself does not have any call to `ini_set` to ensure the default values for `mysql_connect` match the values in the wordpress database configuration.

AFAIK the mysql extension is deprecated, but seems that this plugin uses it. [The documentation for mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) lists the ini values I was talking about.

This means: The mysql_real_escape_string cannot find any link, and so it tries to open a new one, using the ini values. Such ini values are never set by the plugin. This means that, unless I am missing something, the plugin is not linked to the actual Wordpress database settings.

**Question**: Is, what I said, completely true? Do I need to download something that sets the DB configuration to default ini values for mysql extension? Or am I missing something in the plugin configuration? Or should I manually call to `ini_set` for each argument in the DB configuration? If the last one is the answer: Where should I put such calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace `mysql_real_escape_string` with `$this->db->esc_like` in widget.php file.

Comment: you don't need to put your contact detail in your answers. This is not and email!